# Displaying the username of the user who created the node in the node template file

Tags: 7, nodes

I created file node--my_content_type.tpl.php, where I'd like to print the username as string. I tried the following code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. How can I do it?

```
<?php 
  print $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$node->name` will get you the name of the author who submitted the node. It will return it as string, not as link to the user account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet, if I coded <?php print $name; ?>, on the page appears term to the author. Doesn't it matter?

Comment: Yes I know that,since you want to display that as a literal string I gave you $node->name. If you want the name with link you can print $name itself.

Comment: @Ram: thanks i too got it. For me it was coming as links, while printing $name. After i printed $node->name i got as string. cool :)

Comment: I've problem with it. In php code I've 

echo "<div class=\"custom-buy-button\"> <button onclick='buyPhoto(\"<?php print $node->name; ?>\")'>Buy</button> </div>";

and I have function in JS
<script>
  function buyPhoto(user)
  {
    alert(user);
  }
  </script>

Unfortunalety on the sreen appears 
<?php echo admin; ?>

I don't know why in the alert is php tag.

Comment: @user19455: what problem ?

Comment: @user19455: You are already inside an php script, why again using php inside echo statement?

Comment: That's right. I'm stupid. Now, it works perfectly :)

Comment: I ask similar question. If you may, look [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82511/how-to-get-fields-value-programitically) please.

Comment: @user19455: what was wrong with my answer ???

Comment: Why do you think is something wrong? Your answer was helpful.

Comment: @user19455: it was unchecked from being answer few moments ago, so i asked. again back as answer

Answer (score 0):

Usernames are stored in the `$user` object.

```
global $user;
print_r($user);
```

If you mean the fields in a node, those would be in the node object (`$node`).

I highly recommend looking at the output of the above. Get familiar with both the user object and the node object and everything will make a lot more sense.

Comment: Firstly, I copied to my file node.tpl.php file. Now I want to write user who own a given content.

Comment: Could you give me some directions. Unfortunately, I don't know what to do. When I want to write output print $node. There are errors.

Comment: copy `node.tpl` paste and rename as `node--your_content_type.tpl`. The username of node author should be available as `$name`.

Comment: I tried it. I want to have string so I've coded "<?php print $name; ?>", yet it doesn't work. Maybe, for that $name is a term.

Comment: I removed the part answering about the node field, since there is another question asking about that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$user = user_load($node->uid);
print $user->name;
```

This way you can get the name of author by loading the user.