# How do I programmatically get a field's value?

Tags: 7

I copied node.tpl.php and I pasted it to node--my_content_type.tpl.php. My content type has a *price*. How can I get its value as a string?

Comment: For example: You want price field value "2"  to be shown as string  "two" .

Comment: No. If I get price field value 2.0, I want to be shown as string "2.0" or "2".

Comment: Please can you take a little bit more time formulating your questions.  There have been multiple instances where your questions have actually all been the same, and have been posted relatively closely together. The [ask] has some useful tips on asking questions, and the [Help Centre](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) is a useful place to go as well.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the field is displayed in the display settings of your bundle (admin/structure/types/manage/*bundle*/display; replace *bundle* with the machine name of the content type) and define its settings (e.g., delimiter, prefix suffix).

> [image: screenshot]

In your template file, add `<?php echo render($content['your_field_name']); ?>`

Comment: It doesn't work. It's field_name: field value. I want to get only field value·

Comment: Set the label to hidden in your display settings

Comment: I don't understand your directions. Firstly, in my project, url admin/structure/types/manage/bundle/display doesn't exists. Perhaps, may you get some screenshots?

Comment: You don't have to add the field to the display. You can get the field value directly using the $field_machine_name array. Run dpm (if you have devel module enabled) to get the exact structure of the array, it is something like $field_machine_name[0][LANGUAGE_NONE]['safe_value']

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) has the following note.

> Field variables: for each field instance attached to the node a corresponding variable is defined; for example, `$node->body` becomes `$body`. **When needing to access a field's raw values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these variables.** Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired field language; for example, `$node->body['en']`, thus overriding any language negotiation rule that was previously applied.

The description for the `$content` variable is then the following:

> An array of node items. Use [render($content)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) to print them all, or print a subset such as `render($content['field_example'])`. Use [hide($content['field_example'])](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) to temporarily suppress the printing of a given element.

So, if the machine name of that field is field_price, you can get its raw value with `$field_price`, inside the node template file; use `render($content['field_price'])` to render it.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned that `print render($content['field_price']);` doesn't work, so if all else fails - I'd use an `EntityMetadataWrapper`. Although if everything else is failing, then I think you're missing out some vital information and this probably won't work either.

My last resort if all the other suggestions don't work would be preprocessing the node template:

In a module or `template.php`:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (function_exists('entity_metadata_wrapper')) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $vars['node']);
    $vars['price'] = $wrapper->field_price->value();
  }
}
```

Then, in your `node.tpl.php` you can just write `print $price`.

This assumes you have the [EntityAPI](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module installed, which is a pretty fair assumption.

If even this doesn't work, then you need to revisit your actual question, because it's badly written somewhere along the lines.

Answer (score -2):

You can use one of the following code snippets.

```
 $val = $node->field_price[$node->language][0]['value'];
 print ".$val.";
```

```
<?php
  $my_field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_price1');
  if ($my_field_items) {
    $my_field_first_item = reset($my_field_items);
    $my_field_value = $my_field_first_item['value'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: @user19455: Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Probably yes, but I tried and errors appeared. Maybe, I did something wrong. My field is placed in group named group_photo1 and machine name of my field is field_price1. Could you tell me what shoud I write directly. I will be very grateful.

Comment: then try this $node->field_price1['und'][0]['value'];

Comment: $val = $node->field_price1['und'][0]['value'];
print ".$val.";

Comment: I would be inclined to use `$field_price[$node->language][0]['value']` instead of `und`.

Comment: Yes probably that would be best.

Comment: @user19455: Did that help you?

Comment: You shouldn't access field data directly, use `field_get_items()` or an `EntityMetadataWrapper` instead

Comment: What Clive said. I would reverse my -1 to a +1 if the answer primarily recommended either of his suggestions, and discouraged the direct access form.

Comment: If you're going to use `field_get_items()`, then that snippet would be better in a `hook_preprocess_HOOK` implementation. Then you could just use `print $value;` in your template. That's much better than putting logic in your templates.